# Defining private Samba shares

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I'm trying to modify my Linux server's Samba config so that each user gets their own private folder, in a similar way to having a private 'home' folder.

Is it possible to create a samba share that maps to different places, depending on username? E.g if 'bob' connects they see the contents of /documents/bob and if 'fred' connects they see the contents of /documents/fred, and so on?

(I know this is what the [homes] share does, but I want another specifically for each user's private documents that won't get mixed with all the Linux user cruft such as dotfiles and things)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

How about just move Samba homes? For example:

```
[homes]
path=/data/documents/%S
comment = User homes
valid users = %S
read only = No
browseable = No
```

That way, you won't have to see all the "Linux user cruft". You could always symlink the Linux home directory to **/data/documents/%S/linux** or something.